# NetSuite/SuiteScripts Adjusting List Options on the fly

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm trying to remove (or disable) certain list items on a NetSuite form based on the selected option of a different list.  I have been able to alter the form in other ways, using custom code, but the list items appear to be created on the page dynamically.  The field is actually an input field, that is altered by JavaScript, when you "open" it (apparently).

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.  My only other option appears to be to add all of the options to each list programatically (via SuiteScripts), but I'd rather not do that, since there are a lot of lists that need to be altered, depending on other options selected by the client.

EDITED

Well, I found a way, using some of the code from the SuiteScript functions...  It's not ideal, but it could work...  Unless anyone has a better way of doing it...

```
//Add Option
var textCustom = "test inserted option";
var valueCustom = '100';
var selectedCustom = 'T';
var fldnamCustom = 'custevent_fieldNameGoesHere';
var formCustom = document.forms['main_form'];
var fldCustom = getFormElement(formCustom,fldnamCustom.toLowerCase());
if (fldCustom != null){
  addSelectOption(document,fldCustom,textCustom,valueCustom,selectedCustom);
}

//Remove Option
valueCustom2="1";
var formCustom2 = document.forms['main_form'];
var fldCustom2 = getFormElement(formCustom2,fldnamCustom.toLowerCase());
if (fldCustom2 != null){
    eval( valueCustom2 != null ? 'deleteOneSelectOption(fldCustom2, valueCustom2)' : 'deleteAllSelectOptions( fldCustom2, window )' )
}
```